# Synching accountmanager accounts

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter

I am writing an android application that will start sync for all accounts added under "Account & sync" settings.I am fetching all the added accounts using the following code

```
AccountManager am = (AccountManager) getSystemService(Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
Account[]acs = am.getAccounts();
```

After fetching the account I want to start sync for each account

```
for(Account ac:acs){
    ContentResolver.requestSync(ac,authority,extras);
}
```

My question is how do i fetch the authority for the retrieved account ?

Comment: Check this out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#getSyncAdapterTypes()

Answer (score 0):

A far simpler answer is simply to turn off the global sync enabled flag and then turn it back on.  Android starts a full sync by defualt in this case.

See `ContentResolver.setMasterSyncAutomatically()`.

Your app will need appropriate permissions in the manifest to be allowed to change that flag.